# .load() on a new element .createElement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can load a file using a .load() on an element that is in the HTML like this:

```
$("#test").load("/relative/link/here.svg);
```

The issue is that if I now want to load the html into a newly created element that I made with

```
var cont = document.getElementById("test");
var newElement = document.createElement("div");
newElement.className = "view";
$(newElement).load("/relative/link/here");
cont.appendChild(newElement);
```

This doesnt work and it seems because the jquery cannot find the newElement when selecting.  Thank you for any answers.

Comment: Try this - First append the 'newElement' in 'cont' object and then use Load() method to add data into newElement.

Comment: Also try creating a div via jquery - $('<div>').load('/questions/30855904/load-on-a-new-element-createelement')

Comment: The issue is most likely that the "load" hasn't finished when you're trying to append it. I would change your load function to `$( "#result").load( "/relative/link/here", function() {  alert( "Load was performed." ); });` http://api.jquery.com/load/